# QuerySet returning empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a website where users can follow certain stocks and see articles based on the stocks they follow

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class Article(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 0 )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article

def index(request):
    stocks_user_follows = request.user.profile.followed_stocks.all()
    articles_to_display = Article.objects.filter(stock__in=stocks_user_follows) #where the problem lies

    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'stocks_user_follows':stocks_user_follows, 'articles_to_display':articles_to_display})
```

`stocks_user_follows = request.user.profile.followed_stocks.all()` returns the correct value but when I print `{{articles_to_display}}` in index.html there is nothing in the QuerySet which means i must be doing something wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `stock__in=[s.pk for s in stocks_user_follows]`

Comment: Are you sure that there is enough `Article` instance in your DB?

Comment: or try this, `articles_to_display = Article.objects.filter(stock_id__in=stocks_user_follows.values_list('id', flat=True))`